# Thread does not do anything

Tags: c++, multithreading, wxwidgets

I try to use a thread to tell the user the COM port for serial communication he entered was wrong. I have a thread class which tries to establish the connection and a function in my main, that should tell the user. 
The compiler does not complain, but my program never enters the function. Maybe anyone can spot the mistake I made.

main.cpp:

```
WindowsDgpsGUIFrame::WindowsDgpsGUIFrame(wxWindow* parent,wxWindowID id)
{
   ...
   Bind(wxEVT_THREAD, &WindowsDgpsGUIFrame::onConnectionFailed, this, wxID_EXIT);
   ...
}

void WindowsDgpsGUIFrame::OnButtonStartClick(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    NavigationThread* navigationThread = new NavigationThread(this, m_usedVariables);
    m_navigationThread = navigationThread;
    wxThreadError err = m_navigationThread->Create();
    if(err != wxTHREAD_NO_ERROR)
    {
        StaticStatusText->Enable();
        StaticStatusText->SetLabel("Could not create NavigationThread.");
    }
    else{
        StaticStatusText->SetLabel("Thread created");
    }

    err = m_navigationThread->Run();

    if(err != wxTHREAD_NO_ERROR)
    {
        StaticStatusText->SetLabel("Could not run thread.");
    }

}

void WindowsDgpsGUIFrame::onConnectionFailed(wxThreadEvent& event)
{
    StaticConnectionText->SetLabel(event.GetString());
}
```

thread.cpp:

```
wxThread::ExitCode NavigationThread::Entry()
{
    Serial serial;
    int resultGnss = serial.Open(m_gnssPort, STANDARD_BAUDRATE);
    wxThreadEvent event(wxEVT_THREAD, wxID_RETRY);

    if(resultGnss != 0)
    {

        event.SetString("Connection to GNSS box not possible. Try with another COM port.");
        m_parent->GetEventHandler()->AddPendingEvent(event);

    }
    else{
        event.SetString("Connection successful");
        m_parent->GetEventHandler()->AddPendingEvent(event);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The thread gets created and starts running, but even though the event is thrown in the thread the program never reaches `onConnectionFailed()`.

Comment: I have no knowledge on the framework you are using but what seems suspicious to me is that you register to an wxID_EXIT event and you send a wxID_RETRY event which are not the same.

Comment: @Jonathan right, I tried several settings and seemingly forgot to change it in every place. This was the problem.